# Loading an Image using getImage

Tags: java, image, graphics

Here is a simple applet to try loading an image but it shows a blank window

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Mama extends Applet {

int width, height;
Image img;

@Override
public void init(){
    img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "C:\\Users\\......\\Backgound.png");
}

@Override 
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
  }
}
```

I copied the path of the image from the directory, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this path valid? C:\\Users\\......\\Backgound.png? I don't think so

Comment: C:\\Users\\TOSHIBA\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Mama\\Backgound.png

Comment: Did you try giving that path?

Comment: Yes, this is the path I'm using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless they are signed, applets can only read files from the same location from which they were loaded. Move the image to image to a location that is accessible relative to the class (or document) path and use:

```
img = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Backgound.png");
```

Comment: From where does the applet load? I don't understand where to move them.

Comment: @InspiringProgramming Add `System.out.println(getCodeBase());` and this will tell you where to move the image

Comment: Still not showing although I moved the image!! Can it be a problem with the image itself ??

Comment: Tested your code with a regular image and worked fine. Can you try another image?

Answer (score 0):

You can write as here

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class SimpleImageLoad extends Applet {
    Image img;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        img=getImage(getCodeBase(),"file:\\D:\\pic.PNG");
        System.out.println(getCodeBase());
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);
    }
}
```